# Get previous date in node.js

Tags: node.js, date

I have to calculate the previous day to select data from a DB for reporting. It worked until 2016-06-30 but failed at the 1st of July. Instead of getting the date for 2016-06-30 (at the 1st) I got 2016-05-31. My function is called once a day using node-schedule and looks like this:

```
cron.scheduleJob({hour: 0, minute: 5}, function () {
    nowDate = new Date();
    fromDate.setDate(nowDate.getDate() - 1);
    toDate.setDate(nowDate.getDate() - 1);

    logger.info("Started daily reporting ('"+fromDate.getFullYear() + "-" + (fromDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + fromDate.getDate() + " 00:00:00'"+" - '"+toDate.getFullYear() + "-" + (toDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + toDate.getDate() + " 23:59:59')");

    proc.run(fromDate, toDate, function (error) {
        if (error) {
            logger.error(error);
        } else {
            logger.info("Finished daily reporting");
        }
    }); 
});
```

So the output at the 1st of July was:

```
Started daily reporting ('2016-5-31 00:00:00' - '2016-5-31 23:59:59'
```

Any idea why my calculation of the previous day failed?

Comment: As a very general note, date and timezone handling is a pain in the buttocks and I would generally recommend that you use a library like moment.js to avoid having to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the `fromDate` and `toDate` getting declared as a global variable. These dates will get initialized as the day where the application runs, and in your loop you are trying to subtract 1 day off the datetime where this application first started.

Your application may work for the day where it runs but not on subsequent days. To fix the problem the dates will have to be initialized within the `cron.scheduleJob` function.

```
cron.scheduleJob({hour: 0, minute: 5}, function () {
  let yesterdayDate = new Date();
  yesterdayDate.setDate(yesterdayDate.getDate() - 1);
  proc.run(/*from date=*/yesterdayDate, /*to date=*/yesterdayDate, function (error) {
    if (error) {
      logger.error(error);
    } else {
      logger.info("Finished daily reporting");
    }
  });
});
```

If you are intending to do more dates calculation or timezone handling and is looking for an easy reliable way of doing, use [**moment.js**](http://momentjs.com/). It has already been tested and proven by many others in the JS community.

Example of subtracting a day off today's date;

```
"use strict";
var moment = require('moment');

for(let i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
    console.log('lessed ' + i +' day since today = ' + moment().subtract(i, "days").format("DD-MM-YYYY"));
}
```

**Output:**

> lessed 1 day since today = 02-07-2016
>  
>   lessed 2 day since today = 01-07-2016
>   lessed 3 day since today = 30-06-2016
>   lessed 4 day since today = 29-06-2016 
>   lessed 5 day since today = 28-06-2016

Anyway as pointed in the chat the .getDate() implementation has no issue and it works. Here is a little experiment made by me.

```
// Today is 3rd july 2016
nowDate = new Date();
nowDate.setDate(nowDate.getDate() - 1);
nowDate.setDate(nowDate.getDate() - 1);
nowDate.setDate(nowDate.getDate() - 1); // Before deduct = 1st July. 

console.log("Started daily reporting ('"+nowDate.getFullYear() + "-" + (nowDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + nowDate.getDate() + " 00:00:00'");
console.log(nowDate.toDateString());
```

**Output:**

> Started daily reporting ('2016-6-30 00:00:00'
>  Thu Jun 30 2016

Comment: Yes it also works when running this test now ... maybe it's because fromDate and toDate is declared globally and will be initialized just when starting the program?

Comment: @MarkusM - Ok I got a better understanding your use case now. If this is a long running process, that is, once you start the node application you'll leave it running until the machine gets shut down then it can be a problem. Because the from and to dates will be initialized once the app gets started and you are just taking today's day number less whatever it was. I have updated my solution, please review.

Comment: @MarkusM - forgot to mention. If this works for you, would appreciate if you can mark this as answered by clicking on the tick. This is so that future readers can quickly refer to our solution for a possible quick fix. Thanks! Also, if you are still having trouble feel free to let me know.

Comment: I now switched to moment.js which works now for me. Hopefully it will over time